# Función inversa de getTime()

Tags: javascript

Cual sería la función inversa? 
Es decir,como podría obtener d, teniendo e?

```js
var d = new Date()
var e = d.getTime()
console.log(d)
console.log(e)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utiliza el método [`setTime()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_settime.asp). Por ejemplo, acá le *resto* un día (86400000 milisegundos) al valor obtenido en tu ejemplo:

```js
var d = new Date()
var e = d.getTime()
var f = new Date();
f.setTime(e - 86400000);
console.log(d)
console.log(e)
console.log(f);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Uno se desespera con las fechas.

Comment: Si, el tiempo pasa volando ;)

Answer (score 3):

Si tienes e puedes obtener nuevamente la fecha a travez del metodo `setTime` de la clase `Date`

```
var d = new Date('2019-05-10 08:45');
console.log(d);
var e = d.getTime();
var f = new Date();
// Con esto puedes ver que f actualmente tiene la fecha del momento actual
console.log(f);
// Estableces el nuevo valor para la fecha a partir de `e`
f.setTime(e);
// Aki puedes ver como nuevamente armas la fecha a partir de lo que almacenastes en `e`
console.log(f);
```

Comment: Mi respuesta usa una fecha arbitraria para que puedas ver la diferencia, pk si usara new Date() (inicialmente) no ibas a poder notarlo bien

Comment: Te lo agradezco. Simplemente opte por valorar la más rápida, al ser la misma solución. Te valoré con la flechita hacia arriba. Muchas gracias a ti también.

Comment: Jajjaa no hay problema :P